# variable char size without malloc in C

Tags: c, variable-length-array

does `char myStr[varLength]` work in C?

I have the following (code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/H1gGS9hAsP)):

```
int isVMin(char c){
    return c == 'a' || 
            c == 'e' ||
            c == 'i' ||
            c == 'o' ||
            c == 'u' ||
            c == 'y';
}

int isNum(char c){
    return c>='0' && c<='9';
}

int removeChars(char str[]){ // removes all vowels, returns the digits number
    int slen = strlen(str);
    
    //char* res = malloc(sizeof(char)*slen+1);
    char res[slen + 1]; /// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DOES IT WORK AS EXPECTED???

    printf("\nthe initial is: '%s'\n", res);
    int numCount = 0, j = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < slen; i++) {
        if (isVMin(str[i]));
            //str[i]= ' ';
        else { 
            res[j++] = str[i];
            if (isNum(str[i]))
            numCount++;
        }
    }
    res[j] = '\0';
    printf("\nthe removed is: '%s'\n", res);
    //str = res;
    return numCount;
}

int main(){
    char phrase[50];
    gets(phrase);
    
    int nb = removeChars(phrase);
    printf("\nLa phrase '%s' contient %d digits", phrase, nb);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and work as expected. However I have doubts if this usage is legal in C...

Comment: Did it work as expected when you tried? If you're asking "Does C have variable length arrays?" the answer is "Yes".

Comment: no, the question is can I use a variable as array size

Comment: That's precisely what a *variable length array* is. The key is sort of in the name.

Comment: OT: Your `isNum` function duplicates the standard [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) function.

Comment: Tip: [`isdigit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) exists.

Comment: And never ***ever*** use `gets`! It's so dangerous that it has even been removed from the C language specification. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Please,don't use "gets",read this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It does not actually. One difference is theirs works regardless of the signedness of `char`, whereas the behavior of `isdigit` is not defined when it is passed a negative value other than `EOF`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, in C everything is dangerous. and gets is the only method I know to read a line from console without writing miles of lines of code...

Comment: fgets puts the new line char at the end... is crazy this language... such a thing, read a line of text, so complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char res[slen + 1]; /// <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DOES IT WORK AS EXPECTED???
```

This works starting in C '99.

You're kind of limited as to how big. A rule of thumb would be exceeding 8k is probably not recommended. Note that on Windows, if the whole stack exceeds 1mb, the program will crash. On modern Unix. the same thing happens at a larger limit.

You can't return it though. Just sayin'

Comment: Here `strdup()` to get a roughly sized buffer might be a good place to start, then `realloc()` to trim it if that's important.

Comment: you can't return it... ? what do you mean?

Comment: @Serge: It means don't write `char res[slen + 1]; return res;`. If you need to do something like that you need `malloc()` after all.

Comment: why do not return? this language is crazy

Comment: @Serge: This language is not crazy. This language does not do things behind your back and so _cannot implicitly allocate the array on the heap_. The apparent lack of safeguards becomes a really necessary safeguard of its own when doing kernel mode work.

Comment: so, inside the function, it does allocate memory(where on the stack?), but outside, it does not (in the heap?)

Comment: @Serge: Correct about inside. The array goes onto the stack. If you want to live after the function returns, you must allocate it on the heap yourself.